# find the least square solution for the best parabola

Tags: linear-algebra

find the least squares solution for the best parabola going through (1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (4,2)

so to solve this problem I have 4 equation set up

```
  a +  b + c = 1
 4a + 2b + c = 1
 9a + 3b + c = 2
16a + 4b + c = 2
```

I found my $A$ to be

```
1  1  1
4  2  1
9  3  1
16 4  1
```

and my $\mathbf{b}$ to be

```
1
1
2
2
```

then I apply the normal equation $x =(A^TA)^{-1} \, A^T b$ to solve for least square solutions

I got $\mathbf{x}$ =

```
0
0.4
0.5
```

which give me $a = 0, b = 0.4, c = 0.5$

my friend went through similar process and get $a = 0.5, b= 0.4, c = 0$

which should be the right solutions for this problem ?

was it me that getting the reverse answer? or was my answer correct?

thank in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, you set up the quadratic as $ax^2+bx+c$, and your buddy set it up as $a+bx+cx^2$. Either way is OK, so long as when you get to the end you both remember which way you set up your quadratic.

Comment: thank, I just want to make sure that i get the correct answer for the problem

Comment: Well, I haven't checked your calculations, but if you've done your arithmetic correctly, then all you have to do is remember what $a$, $b$, and $c$ stand for, and you should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

You can check your answer using a computer tool such as [R](http://cran.r-project.org/). As you may know what you are doing is **linear regression**, which is accomplished using `lm` in R.

```
> x=c(1,2,3,4)
> y=c(1,1,2,2)
> xx=x^2
> lm(y ~ x + xx)$coeff
  (Intercept)             x            xx 
 5.000000e-01  4.000000e-01 -7.367154e-17
```

So your answers look ok.

You can also perform linear algebra directly in R. In which case, it is useful to know that the function `t` takes the transpose of a matrix, and `%*%` does matrix multiplication. The command `?matrix` will give you help on creating a matrix.

(another tool to consider is [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), which is the open source version of Matlab)

Answer (score 0):

Just a small note, "the best parabola" may be ambiguous term.* If the linear regression is specified in the task, it's clear. However, the metric of squares would suit me more to take the Euclidean distance of the points from parabola. See the code:

```
%% given points
x = [1 2 3 4]; 
y = [1 1 2 2];
N = length(x);

%% optimisation function 1
S1 = @(a) 0;
for k1 = 1:N
 S1 = @(a) S1(a) + dist2(x(k1),y(k1),a);
end

%% optimisation function 2
S2 = @(a) 0;
for k1 = 1:N
 S2 = @(a) S2(a) + (y(k1) - fun(x(k1),a(1),a(2),a(3)) ).^2;
end

a1 = fminsearch(S1,[0 0 0]);
a2 = fminsearch(S2,[0 0 0]); 
%% compare optimising functions
f1S1=S1(a1)
f1S2=S1(a2)
f1S2=S2(a1)
f2S2=S2(a2)

%% plot
xgrid = linspace(0,10,100);
plot(xgrid,fun(xgrid,a1(1),a1(2),a1(3))); hold on;
plot(xgrid,fun(xgrid,a2(1),a2(2),a2(3))); hold on;
scatter(x,y);

%% functions
function f=dist2(x,y,a)
 g = @(t) (x-t).^2 + (y-fun(t,a(1),a(2),a(3))).^2;
 f = fminsearch(g,0);
 f = g(f);
end

function f=fun(x,a,b,c)
 f = a*x.^2 + b*x +c;
end
```

In this case, I would even go further to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#General_case , but there are 5 parameters in a general parabola and only four points. So, there would be solutions including all the points on the parabola.

*And this nuance is definitely not just a mathematical prudence. Imagine for example, that you measured points in a 2D space and you know that your physical trajectory is a parabola. in this case the weight of both coordinates x and y is completely equivalent. I am almost sure that it's not OP's intent in this case. However in these kind of problems, where we usually analyse measured data, it may be good to keep in mind.